# No wifi in virtual machine

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, virtualbox, ubuntu-16.04

I have Ubuntu 16.04 LTS running in Oracle Virtual Box Version 5.1.22 r115126 (Qt5.6.2) over Windows 7 and I can't set up WiFi.

A link to an article on how to set this up would probably be enough to get it done, but I'm not coming up with the right search terms.

Comment: AFAIK VirtualBox (at least the free versions) doesn't virtualize these peripherals. You have to set up the Wifi on the Linux host, which then acts as a router (connected by Ethernet) for the VB guest.

Comment: @xenoid I understand host/guest the other way around. But the procedure remains the same.

Comment: @LotPings Right.... I swapped Linux/Win (I run Win VB in Linux). But the result is the same.

Comment: @xenoid Thanks for the answer. I do have WiFi set up in Win 7, in fact that's how I'm posting this. How do I get Win 7 to act as a router?

Comment: See more complete answer

Answer (score 3):

VirtualBox (at least the free versions) doesn't virtualize these peripherals. You have to set up the Wifi on the host (Windows, for you), which then acts as a router (connected by Ethernet) for the VB guest.

The guest must have a network adapter defined (usually of type `NAT`). Inside the Linux VM

- Interfaces (you should have lo and eth0):

  ```
  $ ip link show
  1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
      link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
  2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
      link/ether 08:00:27:ba:67:7a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
  ```
- Addresses (normally your eth0 interface is 10.0.2.something, the "host side" being 10.0.2.2):

  ```
  $ ip address show
  1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
      link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
      inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
      valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
      inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
      valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
  2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
      link/ether 08:00:27:ba:67:7a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
      inet 10.0.2.15/24 brd 10.0.2.255 scope global dynamic eth0
      valid_lft 85578sec preferred_lft 85578sec
      inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:feba:677a/64 scope link 
      valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
  ```
- Routes (you should have a default route through your host):

  ```
  $ ip route
  default via 10.0.2.2 dev eth0 proto dhcp src 10.0.2.15 metric 100 
  10.0.2.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.2.15 
  10.0.2.2 dev eth0 proto dhcp scope link src 10.0.2.15 metric 100
  ```

AFAIK all this is fairly automatic once you have a network adapter defined on the VM. If all looks good in the VM, check if your Windows host has a network policy that prevents it from acting as a gateway.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try this when I have time and energy, but I really appreciate the time you're taking to help a guy a bit beyond his level of expertise. I'll let you know the results.

Comment: For ip link show, 
2: wasn't eth0:... , it was enp0s3: <NO-CARRIER, BROADCAST, MULTICAST, UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
link/ether 08:00:27:6f:d8:8e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

Comment: NO-CARRIER indicates that your virtual cable is not connected. In the VB GUI, go to Settings>Network>Adapater1>Advanced. Is the "cable connected" box checked? PS: Output of commands should be added to initial question.